# divide one record into multiple ones

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need a query to change this:

```
col1 col2 col3
1    2    abc
3    4    cd
4    5    null
```

To this

```
col1 col2 col3
1    2    a
1    2    b
1    2    c
3    4    c
3    4    d
4    5    NULL
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add (3, 4, 'de') and (4, 5, null) to the sample data, and adjust the result?

Comment: Please post your trial query

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I am not sure I fully understand the question.  Could you please further clarify?

Comment: @JoeTaras I am still trying to find a way... So I don't have anything to share now :)

Comment: If you add the two rows I suggested to your question's sample data, and adjust the expected result, it'd be much easier for everybody to understand what you want.

Comment: @jarlh I added the two records to the sample data.

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this

#### EDIT shorter syntax for the running numbers

#### EDIT2 JamieD77's comment to include the `TOP` into the creation of the numbers

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SingleChars(@SomeText NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
WITH nr10 AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS tbl(A)
)
,RunningNumbers AS
(
    SELECT TOP (ISNULL(LEN(@SomeText),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT(NULL))) AS Nmbr FROM nr10,nr10 AS a,nr10 AS b,nr10 AS c,nr10 AS d,nr10 AS e,nr10 AS f,nr10 AS g
)
SELECT SUBSTRING(@SomeText,Nmbr,1) AS TheCharacter
      ,ASCII(SUBSTRING(@SomeText,Nmbr,1)) AS ASCII_Code
FROM RunningNumbers;
```

A test

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.SingleChars('This is a test');
```

The result

```
T   84
h   104
i   105
s   115
    32
i   105
s   115
    32
a   97
    32
t   116
e   101
s   115
t   116
```

Now your problem

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(col1 INT, col2 INT, col3 VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES(1,2,'abc'),(3,4,'cd'),(4,5,NULL);

SELECT col1,col2,sc.TheCharacter
FROM @tbl
OUTER APPLY dbo.SingleChars(col3) AS sc;
```

The result

```
1   2   a
1   2   b
1   2   c
3   4   c
3   4   d
4   5   NULL
```

Comment: Nice! Any limit on col3's length?

Comment: This `SELECT * FROM dbo.SingleChars(REPLICATE('1234567890',1000));` produces 8000 rows in almost no time :-) So yes, the limit is `VARCHAR`'s limit of 8000 characters...

Comment: (Edited, was "I meant string value length, will it work if col3 contains abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz?") Excellent!

Comment: @jarlh, yes, why not? It will even work with invisible characters like line breaks... The RunningNumber-tally is reduced to the "real" amount with a dynamic `TOP` statement

Comment: I first was confused by the WITH nr10 AS ... (1)... thing.

Comment: @jarlh, well, if not limited the RunningNumbers will go up to anywhere :-) This creation is really fast, about 100 mio numbers in less than a second...

Comment: i have a similar function, but the  `TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0))` part is in the last cte instead of the SELECT.. make any difference with your function?

Comment: @JamieD77 Hi, did some tests now... I think, that your approach with the `TOP` at the Level of creation is more clear, but it seems to lead to the same execution plans. So for this I'd favor yours. The `DATALENGTH` instead of `LEN` is something else: If you define the input variable as `VARCHAR` both functions would return the same count. But if you change your function to accept a `NVARCHAR`, your function would produce the same count of `NULL`s. The `DATALENGTH` function returns the real amount of bytes, `LEN` the count of characters...

Answer (score 2):

In MSSQL you can use [recursive CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Just take one left letter on each step:

```
WITH T1 as 
(
  SELECT col1,col2,LEFT(col3,1) as col4, SUBSTRING(col3,2,10000) as col3 
         FROM Table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT col1,col2,LEFT(col3,1) as col4, SUBSTRING(col3,2,10000) as col3 
         FROM T1 WHERE Col3 <> ''
)

SELECT col1,col2,col4 FROM T1 ORDER BY col1,col2;
```

one more query:

```
WITH T1 as 
(
  SELECT col1,col2,LEFT(col3,1) as col4, col3, 2 as nextPoint  
         FROM Table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT col1,col2,SUBSTRING(col3,nextPoint,1) as col4, col3, 
         nextPoint+1 as nextPoint  
         FROM T1 WHERE LEN(col3)>=nextPoint
)
SELECT col1,col2,col4 FROM T1 ORDER BY col1,col2;
```

Comment: I like yours too. Just for curiosity I checked this with 30.000 rows. Your rec CTE solves the challenge in about 4 seconds (which is pretty fast already), my approach took about 2 seconds. But anyway worth an upvote

Comment: @Shnugo: Thanks (+1 too). Could you try also the second query.